# Copying many files in the Files program takes too long and the speed is extremely slow

Tags: nautilus, performance

When I copy a folder from, say desktop to downloads, the transfer is at astonishingly low speeds. The best it does it 10 Kbps. It is taking very long and draining a lot of my battery. I am new Linux. What should I do?

[image: I have attached the picture here to make it more clear]

You can see the transfer speed at 102 kbps. This file transfer has been taking place for 1.5 hours now. At times this speed goes down to 10-20 kbps.

Comment: Can you provide more info on your setup. Is your downloads folder stored on a different partition or drive to the desktop? It's showing 10 kpbs but is it taking a long time to finish the move? How old is your laptop?

Comment: Where do you see 10 Kbps?

Comment: It's a brand new laptop. I bought it a couple of weeks ago. the laptop came preloaded with Windows, and so I partitioned the disk to boot Linux. I am using 18.04 Ubuntu bionic beaver. I see the speed in the top right corner. When I press _move to_ or _copy to_ I see a small symbol just next to the minimize button.

I don't believe that my download and desktop folders are in different partitions. And yes, even though it shows 10 kbps it is taking even more time.

Comment: Do you have a separate `/home` partition? If yes, what filesystem does it use? NTFS filesystems are notably slow on Ubuntu due to the driver that is used for those filesystems. I'm probably wrong, but this looks like it could be the case here.